# How to convert multiple array type columns in pyspark dataframe to string?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I would like to convert multiple array time columns in a dataframe to string.
Can someone please help?

[Dataframe is like below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/143Yo.png)

I have dataframewith different types of element.Some number/some array.
I want to convert only array columns to string and the rest should be as it is.

Expected Output:
[Expected Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoTWa.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_join` transformation in pyspark. https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_join.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_join

Comment: How can I use it in my case when I want to do it for multiple columns?

Comment: You can use it multiple times and create multiple new columns

Answer (score 1):

I used something like this and that gave me the results:

```
selectionColumns = [F.coalesce(i[0], F.array()).alias(i[0]) if 'array' in i[1] else i[0] for i in df_grouped.dtypes ]
dfForExplode = df_grouped.select(*selectionColumns)

arrayColumns = [ i[0] for i in dfForExplode.dtypes if 'array' in i[1] ]

for col in arrayColumns:
    df_grouped=df_grouped.withColumn(col,F.concat_ws(' || ',df_grouped[col]))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use concat_ws

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat_ws
>>> data_df.show()
+---+---------+---------+---+---+---------------+
| _1|       _2|       _3| _4| _5|             _6|
+---+---------+---------+---+---+---------------+
|  1|[a, b, c]|[c, d, e]| 10| 20|         [a, b]|
|  2|[d, f, h]|   [s, c]| 11| 21|[f, g, h, j, k]|
|  3|[a, f, g]|[r, t, y]| 12| 22|         [g, h]|
+---+---------+---------+---+---+---------------+

>>> df2 = data_df.withColumn("_2",concat_ws(",",col("_2"))).withColumn("_3",concat_ws(",",col("_3"))).withColumn("_6",concat_ws(",",col("_6")))
>>> df2.show()
+---+-----+-----+---+---+---------+
| _1|   _2|   _3| _4| _5|       _6|
+---+-----+-----+---+---+---------+
|  1|a,b,c|c,d,e| 10| 20|      a,b|
|  2|d,f,h|  s,c| 11| 21|f,g,h,j,k|
|  3|a,f,g|r,t,y| 12| 22|      g,h|
+---+-----+-----+---+---+---------+

>>> df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- _1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: string (nullable = false)
 |-- _3: string (nullable = false)
 |-- _4: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _5: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _6: string (nullable = false)
```